# Obtaining integer from String when converting from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, string, numpy, integer, byte

I have a program in python2, however, I am rewriting it in python3.  I read in a netcdf file, and save the variables.  One of the variables should be a string, and I need to turn that string into an integer.  In python 2 I use this method:

```
nums = fid.variables['num'][:]
>>> nums[0]
>>> ['0','1','2','3']

Number = [int(''.join(t)) for t in nums]
>>> Number[0]
>>> 123
```

However, in python 3, the variable, "nums" outputs:

```
>>>nums[0]
>>>[b'0',b'1',b'2',b'3']
```

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.bytes_ found
```

In order to change the type from bytes to strings, I have tried:

```
newNum = [t.decode('UFT-8') for t in nums]
```

but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

***Question:***

How do I turn the string of letters and numbers into an integer?

Comment: I can't reproduce your original behavior in python 2.7

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FS0123'`

Comment: I apologize, that was a mistake on my part,  the variable nums is all numbers - see my edit above

Comment: By the way, it is very curious to me that `nums[0]` is a numpy array, because this: `[b'F',b'S',b'0',b'1',b'2',b'3']` represents a list of bytes. Regardless, you wouldn't be able to decode a container, so you want `newNum = [n.decode('utf8') for t in nums for n in t]`

Comment: Ignore the last comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your edit, your problem is that nums is a container of containers, so your list comprehension isn't working, might I suggest a nested comprehension?:

```
>>> nums = [[b'0',b'1',b'2',b'3'], [b'0',b'1',b'2',b'3']]
>>> [[b.decode('utf8') for b in t] for t in nums]
[['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['0', '1', '2', '3']]
```

Using that approach, you can do what you originally intended:

```
>>> [int("".join(t)) for t in newNums]
[123, 123]
```